# React you cannot pass props inside a regular function but you can pass a prop through a class component

Tags: reactjs

I tried making a class and pass the prop named input under the Time component and the prop renders the prop name however I do the same but instead of using a class I use a function named Kite and try to do the same thing but I get an object error in the console and nothing doesn't render on the page is there a way I can pass a prop through a regular function instead of a class?

```js
function Kite() {
  return (<h1>{this.props.kiteprop}</h1>)
}

class Time extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Test input="dsa" />
        <Kite kiteprop="showtext" />
        <div>{this.props.input}</div>
        <span>{new Date().toLocaleDateString()}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Time input="joe" input="[1, 2]" input="false" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: In a function component, `props` are the function's only argument. In a class component, they are set as a class property automatically. So you would just do `Kite(props)` and then use it as `{props.kiteprop}`.

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks it worked as you probably expected

Answer (score 0):

A better syntax would be:

```
const Kite = (props) => {
    return(<h1>{props.kiteprop}</h1>)
}
export default Kite;
```

And seperating the components into 2 pages of js.

Notice that we pass props into the params of our component, and no need to use `this` here.

Comment: Yea I figured out you could do that as well, but I was trying to see the a way that could been done through a regular function and not a function with a Const assigned to it

Comment: Its the same thing then, doing function Kite(props)